# Losing session Item

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic

I have a website that when I browse from IE9 it loses Session item. This does not happen when using vs to test. This is happening on my pc and on the server where I have it deployed but works from other pcs. I have deleted all cashed pages and have tried multiple logons. So for the last 6 hours I have been banging my head against a wall.

Works when you browse to the site by the ip. Any ideas?

Comment: does the server you have the site deployed on use a load balancer? or is it hosted on just a single box?

Comment: It only happens on my pc or on the server. No one else has issues.

Comment: Have you tried running in compatibility mode?

Comment: I have tried running in compatability mode. I have the exact site running on the same server with no issues. What confuses my is that its jsut on the 2 machines that it doesnt save the session item

Comment: OK so new information. IE9 doesnt work on any machine ie10 works fine. If I browse to the site by the IP it works fine.

Comment: +1 on the question for working it out and giving the reason for the problem.

Comment: Please add your answer below. Or close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cookies enable on your PC.

Seem to recall I had a similar problem.

If cookies are not enabled then the session variables does not work.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1804941.aspx/1?Session+Variables+make+use+of+cookies+

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Jason Akin (original asker):

---

**Issue was caused by an underscore in the host name. Evidently this is not something you should do. Took a while to figure this out. Well leason learned.**

Hopefully this will help someone else out.